Issue with Network adapter “Qualcomm Atheros ar9485
I am trying dualboot Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS with Windows 8.1 (Yes I know it’s old) but having issues with my Network adapter.
Upon running iwconfig I get the output
lo    no wireless extensions.

eno1.  no wireless extensions.

wlo1   IEE 802.11 ESSID:off/any
       Mode:Managed Acess Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=off Retry short limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off Power Management:off. 

And upon running rfkill list I get the output
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes


The "Hard blocked: Yes" from rfkill shows that your Wireless interface is disabled by a hardware switch, usually controlled by a key or key combination on your laptop's keyboard.

Already tried to use the physical hardware switch, however it does nothing
